# Autofac & ASP.NET Core : why ASP.NET Core cannot reach ConfigureContainer method at Startup inheriting from StartupBase?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac, autofac-configuration

## Description:

I am creating a ASP.NET Core application using Autofac, so I am following the documentation given for it: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html, should a be pretty straightforward path to follow, but I do have a problem, my Statup class inherits from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StartupBase which makes me implement the next :

```
public abstract class StartupBase : IStartup
{
      protected StartupBase();

      public abstract void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app);
      public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services);
      public virtual IServiceProvider CreateServiceProvider(IServiceCollection services);
}
```

so far everything fine, my Statup class looks like this

```
public class Startup : StartupBase
{
  readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;

  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
  {
     //some stuff here
  }

  public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
     //some other stuff here
  }

  // https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html
  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
     builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());        
  }

  public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
  {
     //more stuff here
  }     
}
```

and the Program.cs, just for example purpose this is some example

```
public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    // The ConfigureServices call here allows for
    // ConfigureContainer to be supported in Startup with
    // a strongly-typed ContainerBuilder.
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddAutofac())
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
  }
}
```

### Problem:

Once the application starts running it should hit the ConfigureContainer method, but it doesn´t and I do not know why, which means that I cannot inject anything registered in the AutofactModule class, I manage to solve this but I want to know what is happening behind scenes,

### Fix:

I have deleted the inheritance from StartupBase and everything went fine

### Theory:

I suspect that somehow Autofac in the .UserStartup gets the base class and tries to get the methods from it, but I cannot prove it and could not find the right words to search for it. **Can somebody explain me why the simple inheritance is a problem here?.**

Comment: @Gibbon is right - this is totally an ASP.NET Core thing, nothing to do with Autofac. You can probably get more eyes on this if you update the tags and the question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this is actually more a microsoft thing than an Autofac thing - within the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` namespace is a `StartupLoader` Class [Github Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/964b671288d95ee659d2119f3c3d9831c70b81db/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Internal/StartupLoader.cs). This is what actually chooses which methods are called. It has an interesting quirk (design choice) of not calling the Autofac methods - there have been a couple of related issues raised on the github though have generally been closed as it seems to be a design choice that they dont intend to change